# How do I reset the pointer to the head node when adding to nodes?

Tags: c, trie

I need to start with the head node every cycle to add the new node in the right place. I think my current code makes the pointer for head and sptr equal so when I move one, the other one moves too. How do I move the pointer  sptr to the beginning?

In debugger `head->letter[1]` turns true when I save an "a" as a word as it should, but later turns back to false as soon as `sptr = head;` runs. I think it has to do with the pointers.

```
typedef struct node
{
    bool exist;
    struct node* letter[28];
} trie;

trie *head = NULL;
int words = 0;

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    int i = 0;

    FILE *infile = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (infile == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open %s.\n", dictionary);
        return 1;
    }
    // allocate memory
    head = calloc(sizeof(trie), 1);
    head->exist = false;
    trie *sptr = head;
    int cr;

    // loop through file one character at a time
    while ((cr = fgetc(infile)) != EOF)
    {
        // build a trie
        // check if it's end of line
        if (cr != 10)
        {
            i = tolower(cr) - 96;
            // check for apostrophy
            if (i < 0)
            {
                i = 0;
            }
            // check if the position exists
            if (sptr->letter[i] == NULL)
            {
                sptr->letter[i] = malloc(sizeof(trie));
                sptr->exist = false; // not the end of the word
            }
            sptr = sptr->letter[i];
        }
        else // indicate the end of a word that exists
        {
            sptr->exist = true;
            sptr = head;// I think the problem might be here, I'm trying to move the pointer to the beginning.
            words++;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: `sptr->letter[i] = malloc(sizeof(trie));` is definitely a problem. The pointers in the allocated node are not initialized.

Comment: @sagi: multiplication is commutative; it makes no difference which order the two numbers are provided to `calloc()`.

Comment: @user58697 - I'm not running into any memory issues that I know of (other than leaking since I'm not freeing it yet). The program runs fine but the values I expect t find in "exist" are not correct. My original comment should have read head->letter[1]->exist changes values. Does sptr = head move sptr back to the first node?

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I checked using debugger and sptr = head does what it is supposed to. My problem lies somewhere else, and I'm not providing enough info here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. It was in line sptr->exist = false, it should've read sptr->letter[i]->exist = false. The pointer was moving fine but I was changing the value of where the current pointer was, not the newly created node.